# Javascript React onclick event on rendered prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, dom

i am making movie app clone. I have function which is mapping object of API call and returning array of values. Values are then rendered as span on html. How can i implement funcion which will show which value is clicked?(or store it and make another api call with this value as argument for example).

```
 function genres(genre_ids) {
    const newArr = genre_ids.map(myFunction);
    function myFunction(num) {
      switch (num) {
        case 12:
          return "Adventure";
          break;
        case 28:
          return "Action";
          break;
        case 16:
          return "Animation";
          break;
        case 35:
          return "Comedy";
          break;
      return newArr.join("/");
```

Genre_ids is api response. I am rendering it as for example : **Action/Adventure/Science Fiction**.
This value is rendered as:

```
  <Card.Text>
              <div>
                <span style={{ fontSize: "15px" }}>{genres(genre_ids)}</span>
              </div>
```

How can i add onclick event on every element of render genres?
Thank You :)

Comment: If you want individual genres to be clickable you should have rendered the nodes first before joining them with slashes.

Comment: @Terry thank You. I removed `.join` method.  TypeOf newArr is Object which is now rendered without slashes. But how can i add on click to rendered properties object ? Thats the confusing part for me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that text by itself isn't able to track which word you're clicking on, so each word in the listed genres will need wrapped with a dom element that can handle a DOM onClick action. You'll then use `useState` to track the genreId that has been clicked. To implement this, I would create a new `<Genres>` component instead of using your `genres()` function; we can use the index of the genre to determine if it should be preceded with a slash or not:

---

New component:

```
const genreIdMap = {
  12: 'Adventure',
  16: 'Animation',
  28: 'Action',
  35: 'Comedy',
};

const Genres = ({ genreIds, updateSelectedGenre }) => (
  <>
    {genreIds.map((genreId, index) => (
      <React.Fragment key={genreId}>
        {index > 0 && <>/</>}
        <span onClick={() => updateSelectedGenre(genreId)}>{genreIdMap[genreId] ?? 'Unknown'}</span>
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
  </>
);
```

---

Where your current JSX lives:

```
// inside parent component
const [selectedGenre, updateSelectedGenre] = useState(null);
const { genre_ids } = props; // or wherever you're getting this value from

return (
  <Card.Text>
    <span style={{ fontSize: "15px" }}>
      <Genres genreIds={genre_ids} updateSelectedGenre={updateSelectedGenre} />;
    </span>
  </Card.Text>
);
```

---

Note that we pass the `setState()` function (named `updateSelectedGenre` in this case) down to the `<Genres>` component to use in the onClick, but it's the parent component tracking that state so you can use it however you need.

In the end, this will generate DOM like:

```html
<span>
  <span>genre1</span>/<span>genre2</span>/<span>genre3</span>
</span>
```

but where the inner spans have the onClick function

Comment: hmm, const Genres, or funcion genres in my case is not component, only function inside my main component. I also have map allready here, thank You for your code but i cant understand it without explanation :(. I edited question to make it more clear.

Comment: OP created a Genre component for you in the first code block. It’s just an abstraction from the logic so that you don’t have to do it in the JSX template directly.

Comment: @JSpadawan Sorry for the late reply here. What you are doing with functions is actually where you want to use a new react component, which is a special function that allows you to break your JSX up nicely. I created the <Genres /> component in the first half of the answer to replace your genres() function, the 2nd half should go where your existing JSX that you posted is.

Comment: @JSpadawan I have also updated my answer to reflect your changes for turning the genreId into a label (though I suggest you store and get the labels from wherever you're getting the IDs from if possible, instead of duplicating that mapping here)